# Degeneration to a hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory

Let $X\to T$ be a flat familiy of curves of genus $g$ where $T$ is a smooth curve over a field $K$. Assume that for $t_0\in T$ the fiber $X_{t_0}$ is hyperelliptic and for all other $t\in T$ the fiber $X_t$ is not. Is it then always possible to construct a flat family $Y$ of degree $2g-2$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ over $T$ such that for $t\neq t_0$ the fiber $Y_t$ is $X_t$ canonically embedded? What would $Y_{t_0}$ be in that case? Is it (as a set) the rational normal curve of degree $g-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is exactly what's studied in

Lung-Ying Fong, Rational ribbons and deformation of hyperelliptic curves, J. Algebraic Geom. 2 (1993), no. 2, 295–307.

You can take the relative canonical sheaf of the family and map it to $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}_T$ and take the scheme-theoretic image. The first main result in Fong's paper is that the fiber over $t_0$ is a non-reduced curve which is a double structure on the rational normal curve. They're called ribbons and you can find more about them in

Dave Bayer and David Eisenbud, Ribbons and their canonical embeddings, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 347 (1995), no. 3, 719–756